# Can a broken power supply connector cause a laptop to overheat?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have (or had!) a Microsoft Surface Laptop 4 which I bought about 18 months ago, and had found to be a very good laptop which has been halfway around the world with me and not had any problems.

Although the power supply unit failed after only a few months and had to be replaced, and while I was waiting for a replacement, I bought a cheap(ish) unofficial copy PSU, so ended up with two PSUs - one replacement official one and one cheap copy, which was good because I could leave one upstairs and one downstairs. I used either with no problems for about a year.

Just recently I noticed that the cheap copy was charging intermittently, and on closer inspection, that the connector was damaged - I think I'd actually trod on it! The connector type is I believe specific to Microsoft Surface laptops and is called a Surface Connect Port (or perhaps Microsoft Connect Port). It has has some copper connectors at either end of the barrel/blade and the middle is plastic, the plastic in the middle had come away, but most of the connectors were intact... I then found that the PSU with the slightly broken connector would charge the laptop intermittently, depending on how the connector was seated in the charging port.

But... in retrospect, I did notice that the laptop, which never usually got particularly hot, even when use in 34C heat in Thailand, was getting... very hot... and then the screen went black, and it never worked again. I took it to a computer repair place and they tried doing a POST (Power On Self Test) with an external monitor attached via USB-C/HDMI, but there was nothing. It is still under warranty, so once I have a copy of the data from the SSD (which is an M.2 2242), I will send it to the vendor and hopefully they will replace it, as we think the motherboard is fried.

My question is, could the broken and intermittently-charging PSU have cause the laptop to overheat, and how does this happen? And also, how might this have happened despite temperature sensors which I would have thought would have shut the machine down before it got anywhere near temperatures that could damage it?

Comment: Superuser.com is the correct site. That said, the answer looks - like some electronics specialist needs to look into it. I have no idea whether a PSU can pump more than the needed power into a laptop to start with.

Comment: “My question is, could the broken and intermittently-charging PSU have cause the laptop to overheat, and how does this happen?” Most likely, yes. Temperature sensors might not operate correctly with incorrect power flow. Honestly, the answer here is a complete , “Maybe…” My advice is to just get the data off of the device and if you are going to use a replacement AC adapter in the future, use a legitimate replacement. Either an official replacement or one from a legit manufacturer.

Comment: Without the device itself and thus no ability to test any solution provided, this question cannot be answered with anything other than "maybe..." it's not a bad question, but this site is about questions that can be answered.

Comment: Well thanks for saying that it's not a bad question... the laptop in question is dead, fried, so it doesn't really matter in that case. But for potential future cases, in the general case, I'd like to know how this could have happened - partly in case I have to use a non-legit or legit but faulty power supply in the future - it can happen, when travelling. It's somewhat academic, but I bet there's someone out there who would know what actually happened, and how. "Temperature sensors might not operate correctly with incorrect power flow" sounds plausible, for instance.

Comment: I had a non-legit Macbook power supply actually go "pop!" with a whiff of smoke in hostel in Thailand and then spent the next couple of days trying to find a replacement charger until I realised that there is an Apple store in Bangkok and they sold me a legit charger, which then worked fine for the rest of my travels. Turns out not all mains electricity is the same - especially in cheap hostels! OK, so use an official charger, I got that, I learned my lesson - but what I'm interested in is what's actually going on inside - the electrics, if that's the right word.